# How to run EC2 reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have right now AWS free tier instance. I purchased a m3.large reserved instance. Now how can i run and use this as i was using free tier instance .

I cant see any start/stop option for reserved instance.

Answer (score 5):

Reserved instances are purely an accounting/billing thing. There is not a special way to "run" a reserved instance. Simply run an instance that matches the specifications of your reserved instance purchase and it will run at the reserved instance rate rather than the on-demand rate.

Basically AWS billing sees that you're running an instance for the hour. They check to see if there is a reserved instance purchased that matches the specifications of the running instance. If one is found, that hour is billed at the reserved rate. If one is not found, then you're charged at the on-demand rate.

Comment: how will i know that my reserved instance is being used?

Comment: @Manish You'll see the lower cost reflected in your billing.

Comment: means i will have to wait for month last or there is no way to know this from ec2 console

Comment: You can see it in your current bill before month-end.